# WordPress - Get Posts by Date

Tags: php, date, wordpress

I am trying to figure out how to construct a WordPress query that is going to get posts by date.

What I mean by this, is that I'd like a way to output my WordPress posts something like this:

```
<div class="day-posts">
     <div class="day">
          <div class="title">Monday 1st January 2014</div>
          <div class="posts">
               <div class="post">
                    <div class="title">Post for this day</div>
                    <div class="content">Lorum ipsum dolar sit amet</div>
               </div>
          </div>
     </div>
     <div class="day">
          <div class="title">Tuesday 2nd January 2014</div>
          <div class="posts">
               <div class="post">
                    <div class="title">Post for this day</div>
                    <div class="content">Lorum ipsum dolar sit amet</div>
               </div>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

This needs to work with posts that are not published yet also, using the "post_status=future" query option.

I have spent about an hour searching online to see if someone has done something like this before, but unfortunatly I haven't found anything viable.

I have also made some attempts at this myself but unfortunatly, I haven't been able to come up with anything that works.

Does anyone have some suggestions or insights on how this might be done?

Thanks

Comment: I've read your question and have no idea what it is you're trying to accomplish. You want to list future posts by date, starting at a certain date and going forward in ascending order?

Comment: It should work with all posts, both published and scheduled (hence the post status variable). Yes, I want to list posts by day and I plan to use jQuery to display one day at a time, with arrows to navigate to the next or previous date.

Comment: are you sure you want to display these? when set to future date single template loop will not show contents for **NONE EDITORS** aka normal users, it will create more problems when you get the above to work

Comment: There isn't going to be a single page template for what I am doing. I am querying a custom post type and the results will only be showed on one page, with no links or need to a single template.

Comment: Does `WP_Query` orderby `post_date` not work? [WP Query Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) or is there a key point I'm missing here?

Comment: It works but, each days posts need to be seperated into a container div so that I can apply jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$query = new WP_Query(array('orderby' => 'post_date', 'order' => 'DESC')); //Orders posts by post_date in descending order

// The Loop
if ($query->have_posts()) {
    echo '<div class="day-posts">';
    while ($query->have_posts()) {
        $query->the_post();
        echo '<div class="day">';
        the_date('l jS F Y', '<div class="title">', '</div>'); //Formats date, before echo, after echo
        echo '<div class="posts">';
        echo '<div class="post">';
        the_title('<div class="title">', '</div>'); //echo title
        echo '<div class="content">';
        the_content(); //echo content
        echo '</div></div></div></div>';
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

I put this together in a few minutes, sorry I didn't concatenate and make it all nice, but you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

Although at first glance it looks like a simple task, it is tricky to build a nested loop with a single query.

First step is to build a query, for the demonstration I will take all posts ( `posts_per_page=-1` ) in ascending order ( `order=asc` ) with any post status ( `post_status=any` ). Post status can be changed by using array of arguments like `'post_status' => array( 'publish', 'future' )` ( [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Status_Parameters) ).

Next step is to build multidimensional array of posts:

```
$posts_by_day = array_reduce( $query->posts, function( $r, $v ) {
    $r[ date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( $v->post_date ) ) ][] = $v;
    return $r;  
});
```

An array that looks like:

```
    Array
    (
        [2014-03-17] => Array
            (
                [0] => WP_Post Object ( ... )
                [1] => WP_Post Object ( ... )
        )
        [2014-03-24] => Array
            ( 
                [0] => WP_Post Object ( ... )
                [1] => WP_Post Object ( ... )
                [2] => WP_Post Object ( ... )
        )
        ...
    )
```

And finally loop through an array, by date in the outer loop, and by posts on that date in the inner loop. [setup postdata()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata) is used to set up a global post data so that Template Tags can work in the current post context.

```
<?php
    $query = new wp_query( 'post_status=any&order=asc&posts_per_page=-1' );

    $posts_by_day = array_reduce( $query->posts, function( $r, $v ) {
        $r[ date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( $v->post_date ) ) ][] = $v;
        return $r;  
    });
?>

<?php if ( $posts_by_day ) : ?>
    <div class="day-posts">
    <?php foreach( $posts_by_day as $day => $day_posts ) : ?>
        <div class="day">
            <div class="title"><?php echo date( 'l jS F Y', strtotime( $day ) ); ?></div>
            <div class="posts">
            <?php foreach( $day_posts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
                <div class="post">
                    <div class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
                    <div class="content"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
                </div>          
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>
        </div>  
    <?php endforeach; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Hey. Brandon Gelfand already posted a solution that appears to work. I am going to test yours as well and see how it functions. I appreciate your answer. As you said, this initially looks like a simple question but its actually quite hard! I spent a couple hours trying to solve it before posting here, so thank you!

Comment: Solution from Brandon works only if you have one post per day.

Comment: That isn't true. I have tested it with multiple posts per day.